# Integral of complex exponential in radial coordinates with argument r^2cos(2\theta)

Tags: integration

The integral I am trying to do is:

$\int_0^{1} \int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{iar^2cos(2\theta)}rdrd\theta = \int_0^{1} \int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{iar^2}e^{-2ia(rsin(\theta))^2}rdrd\theta$

I am stuck with this integral that I can't seem to find a good trick for. If anyone has a hint or suggestion it would be much appreciated! The main trick I was trying is using the integral definitions of Bessel functions $J_n(z) = \frac{i^{-n}}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi} e^{izcos(\theta)}cos(n\theta)d\theta$ but to no avail due to the argument being $r^2cos(2\theta) = r^2(1-\sin^2(\theta)) = r^2 - (rsin(\theta))^2$. The integral over the radial direction is some finite value.

If it is rewritten using Euler's formula as well it doesn't put it into a obvious form that I am familiar with. Maybe doing that makes it easier, but I'm not sure...

Comment: Use $\sin(\theta)=\cos(\theta-\pi/2)$, then change variables $u=\theta-\pi/2$. The integral limits are still over one period of the periodic integrand so you may set those to $0,2 \pi$. This yields the integral representation for $J_0(ar^2)$. The remaining integrand is $r J_0(a r^2)dr$, which Mathematica evaluates to a HypergeometricFPQ function.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks for the help, I didn't think of doing that substitution! I shall be using that result!